# Inverse perspective in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm getting inverse perspective in OpenGL ES application. Objects that are further from camera appear to be larger, and objects that are closer appear to be smaller. This is absolutely inverse to normal perspective. 
Here is screenshot:

[image: http://imgur.com/TWCKb]

In this screenshot, cube is actually closer than sphere but due to incorrect perspective it looks smaller.

Object in 3ds max, cube and sphere have the same size:

[image: http://imgur.com/Hb48o]

Please explain what can be a cause of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something may be wrong with the projection matrix, but it looks like issue with depth buffer.

Make sure you are using correct order in `glFrontFace`. Make sure you enabled `GL_DEPTH_TEST` and you are clearing with `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT`. Finally make sure you are not using weird `glDepthFunc`.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was in wrong `glDepthFunc()` and `GLES20.glClearDepthf()`